# How does solr work with autowarm?

Tags: solr

In solrconfig.xml, the 'autowarmCount' of filterCache(or queryResultCache and etc) indicates how many cache entity will be copied when a new searcher come. However, if I add or delete doc in solr, there may be invalid cache entity exists in old searcher. I think it's not a good idea that copy cache entity to new searcher, am I right?

Answer (score 10):

I can try to explain what I know about autowarm.

A filter cache is a mapping between a filter query and unordered set of internal document IDs which match the filter query. After commit an old searcher is invalidated and a new searcher is created. The new searcher should fill the filter cache from the old one. It can not copy old values of cache (unordered set of internal document IDs) because they could be changed, but it can copy keys (filter queries) and rerun queries from the old cache. New results of the queries will be added to the new filter cache.

Query result cache uses the same approach.

And you should remember that a document cache does not use autowarm feature because keys of the cache is internal IDs and they are changed after commit operation and the new searcher can not use old cache keys (internal document IDs) in order to repopulate the new cache.

I would appreciate if someone would describe the work of autowarm more details and more clearly.